# Missing $ or inserted extra

Tags: latex

I am writing an equation using latex.

```latex
\begin{equation} \label{Pearson}
\begin{tabulary} {18cm}{L R @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} L}
&Sim_{a,b}^{PCC}& = & $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{P\in P}( r_{a,p} - \overline {r}a)( r_{b,p} - \overline{r}b)} {{\sqrt{\sum_{P\in P}( r_{a,p}-\overline{r}a)^2}}{\sqrt{\sum_{P\in P}( r_{b,p} - \overline{r}b)^2}}}$
\end{tabulary}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: using `tabulary` inside an equation seems rather strange. Can you make a sketch how the resulting equation should look like? Maybe there are better ways to achieve the desired result. For example `align` comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got you. `tabulary` is definitely not needed here, since you want to type an equation. My minimal code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{Pearson}
\mathrm{Sim}_{a,b}^{PCC} = %
\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{P\in P}(r_{a,p} - \overline{r}a) (r_{b,p} - \overline{r}b)}%
{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{P\in P}(r_{a,p} - \overline{r}a)^2}%
 \sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{P\in P}(r_{b,p} - \overline{r}b)^2}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

will give you this output:

[image: output equation]

Please confront it with yours!